# How to read from Active MQ without deleting the contents in Talend

Tags: database, activemq-classic, etl, talend

I am currently using tMomInput to read from Active MQ. 
Is there any way in Talend that we can read from a Queue in Active MQ without deleting? Is it possible to delete the contents only when they are successfully copied over to a temporary table? If there is a failure such as server shut down and the job fails before copying them to the DB table then there will be no way of recovering the data.

Answer (score 0):

The general way to do this in JMS is to use transactions. This way the message is only deleted from the queue when the transaction is committed in the success case. In the error case the transaction is rolled back and the message is given back to the jms server for retransmit.